# A conjecture about $8n+6$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

Can you provide a counterexample to the claim given below ?

Inspired by Euler's conjecture about $8n+3$ (see page 4 of [this note](http://sigmaa.maa.org/pom/PomSigmaa/Mazur1-12Details.pdf) ) I have formulated the following claim :

> For any nonnegative integer $n$ , $8n+6$ can be represented as a sum :
>   $$8n+6 = a^2 +2p$$ ,
>   where $a$ is a nonnegative integer , and $p$ is a prime .

I have tested this claim for all $n$ up to $2 \cdot 10^6 $ .

Comment: On page 240 of Mathematical Cranks, Underwood Dudley discusses the conjecture that every number of the form $4n+3$ can be written as the sum of a square and twice a prime, except 79. He opines the conjecture is false.

Comment: Why does Dudley believe this is false?  This strikes me as the sort of conjecture that's likely to be true except for a few small exceptions.

Comment: @GerryMyerson . I read "A Budget Of Trisectors" by Underwood Dudley. Is "Mathematical Cranks" a different  version of it, or a separate book?

Comment: @Michael, he doesn't give any reason. Note the use of the at-sign if you want to be sure someone see a comment.

Comment: @Daniel, I found an "about the author" which says, "He is the author of three books on mathematical oddities, The Trisectors, Mathematical Cranks, and Numerology."

Comment: I can confirm that the conjecture is true for $8n + 6 \leq 10^9$.

Comment: @Dylan Thank you for your investigation !

Answer (score 1):

I cannot prove the assertion, but I can prove that $p\geqslant 5$.

---

*Proof*: $$8n+6 = 2(4n+3)$$ and so is always even. Therefore, $a^2 + 2p$ must also be even, so $a^2$ is even and hence $a$ is also even. It follows, then, that for some $b\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, we have $a = 2b$. Thus, $$\begin{align} 2(4n+3) &= 4b^2 + 2p\tag*{$\big($Since $(2b)^2 = 4b^2\big)$} \\ &= 2(2b^2 + p).\end{align}$$ Therefore, $4n+3=2b^2+p$. Now we know that $2b^2$ can never be a square number itself (which is why $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational), so when $n = c^2$ for some $c\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, it follows that $4c^2\neq 2b^2$. And so, $p\neq 3$.

Now if $p=2$, then $4n+1=2b^2$ which is obviously absurd. Thus, $p > 2,3$ if (and only if!) $$p\geqslant 5.\tag*{$\bigcirc$}$$

Comment: Your conjecture, in other words, is that $$4n+3=2b^2 + p\tag*{$\left(\begin{align}&\text{for non-negative integers $b$} \\ &\text{and $n$, and a prime $p\geqslant 5$.}\end{align}\right)$}$$